# android Programming by using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I'm a beginner of Android Application development need to practice by examples and samples given in the book "Beginning with Android" by Wei Meng Lee, but whenever I try to follow those steps I come across a few errors unable to clean them. The Error seems like this: 
"  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" Don't know what type of error is it. In my computer I've installed SDK API level 16 that is for Android 4.1 What to do? Please guide me through appropriate answer.

Comment: check out your xml layout name which matches your setcontent view declaration

Comment: post your xml &  main code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove import

```
import android.R;
```

Than clean build your project also check xml layout file name in

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

than it'swork fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the latest version of eclipse. Its now Eclipse Juno.

And check your import.
Remove

```
import android.R;
```

Instead put

```
import android.packagename.R;
```

Comment: Actually, in all likelihood, he should just remove it entirely. Additionally, it's doubtful that his package will have `android.` as a prefix. (And it shouldn't.)